# Calculating string from other cell

Tags: google-sheets, calculation

In cell A I have text like `1+4+8+2` to show what we are counting, in next cell B I would want the sum/value of that, in this case `15`.

Is this somehow possible?

Point is that I would not have to write the calculation every time, but it would count it automatically if I just copy the B cell to next row.

Comment: So, you want to evaluate the text in a cell as a formula?

Comment: yes, the B cell would take the A cell, count the value of it and show the sum value only.

Comment: Ok, so no other option but to do a custom function that does the job. thanks

Comment: =SUM(SPLIT(A1,"+")) will be work fine.

Comment: @pnuts Fair 'nuff, voted to reopen too. However, as I read the question, text is not necessarily restricted to a `+`-separated list of integers. If it is, question should be edited to clarify this.

Comment: @Hetsku55 Are you looking for general formula evaluation, or just summing a list of numbers with `+` as separator?

Comment: Mostly summing numbers with + as separator, but would not want to rule out possibility to use others (-,/,*)

Comment: @NitinDhomse This was the answer i was looking for, although i had to change the , to ; to make it work. thanks! i would vote your comment up but not enough rep yet.